# Row count of DAX-aggregation (or pagination) with SSAS tabular direct query

Tags: ssas, dax

Read the Questions section right away if you don't need to know why. :)

**Tech used**

- SSAS Tabular on premise windows server
- DAX Query through IIS

**Background**

Our front end environment sends requests with a DAX query to get data from our on premise SSAS Tabular model. We support customers with their sales data for interactive drill down.

The front end app has a hard time handling (unmarshalling) big amounts of data in a single request and asks for pagination of around 25000 rows (sending chunks of rows in multiple requests).

We have tested and this could increase performance a lot (due parallelism in GO-lang used in the app). We would like to support the front end app with this.

**Assumed Problem**

- There is no way to get pagination of the repsonse.

**How to solve this without pagination**

1. Split into subqueries per country based on number of rows returned in the aggregated data set for said country. (if > 25000 then query per quarter etc).
2. Get TOP rows skipping m rows. The requests could loop until result is empty. (TOPNSKIP() function would be great but does not seem to be fully developed yet.)

**Questions**

- Is there any way to count number of rows returned in an aggregation response (the query below)?
- Is there any other way to paginate the aggregated answer?

**What We have tried**

- A lot of dax functions for counting rows, but none see to be able to count rows in an aggregation.
- Aggregating the fact data so that row count is the same as aggregated count. Cannot be done since we for example: the fact joins on date but aggregation does not contain date. We could of course create a whole new model just for this case but that is a last resort.

**The query used today (simplified to sales as an exampel)**

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    Date[YearQuarter],
    TypeOfSale[TypeCode],
    Country[CountryCode],
    Product[Product],
    FILTER ( Customer, Customer[CustomerId] = 15 ),
    FILTER ( Date, Date[YearQuarter] IN { "2020-Q1" , "2020-Q2" } ),
    "Amount", SUM ( Sales[Amount] )
)
```